# Customizing X axis Highcharts, adding custom markers under the X axis

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to implement this use case as the attached image.

Creating this custom chart using Highcharts the chart ticks are inside the chart the issue I'm facing is adding some custom markers under the X axis for some values (The yellow ones with +).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now the only way seems to be to use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class and create custom shapes - `circle`, `text` and `path`. You can easy calculate pixels position based on x-axis and y-axis through `toPixels` method.

Example:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
      yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
      r = 10,
      distance = 40,
      y = yAxis.toPixels(0),
      x = xAxis.toPixels(3);

    this.renderer.text('+', x, y + distance + r, 'circle')
      .css({
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
      }).add();

    this.renderer.circle(x, y + distance, r).attr({
      fill: '#FCFFC5',
      stroke: 'black',
      'stroke-width': 1
    }).add();

    this.renderer.path(['M', x, y, 'L', x, y + distance - r])
      .attr({
        'stroke-width': 1,
        stroke: 'black'
      })
      .add();
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ukfocb7y/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

Comment: Than you @ppotaczek, very helpful!